# Remove specific section of string

Tags: python, regex, string

Hi I have a file that contains several thousand file paths that I am looking to move to Wazhu. Problem is I need directories so what I have looks like
`>/apples/oranges/test.ex<` What I need is `>/apples/oranges<`
Not sure if Regex or just using `str.replace()` is better. As each line is different I would need to find the last `/` and remove it as well as everything up to `<`

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: `s[:s.rindex("/")] + s[-1:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write

```
import re

s = '>/apples/oranges/test.ex<'

re.match(r'.*(?=\/)', s).group()
```

which returns

```
>/apples/oranges
```

This works because `.*` is greedy, so it consumes all forward slashes up to the last one. `(?=\/)` is a *positive lookahead*. `group(0)` also works.

[Demo](http://tpcg.io/YZFZjpm4)

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's way using the split and join methods:

```
s = '>/apples/oranges/test.ex<'
s = '/'.join(s.split('/')[:-1])+'<' # Splits s by '/', remove the last object, join them together, plus a '<'
print(s)
```

#### Output:

```
>/apples/oranges<
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need regex to do this. You can simply use:
[os.path.split](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)

```
import os
head, tail = os.path.split("/apples/oranges/test.ex")
print(head)
Output: /apples/oranges
```

I was stuck with the same issue, the above method solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Try `/[^/\r\n]*<$` replace this `<`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/LzHrHI/1)

Answer (score 0):

you mean you want only everything except for the last "/"?

```
import os

file = open('file.txt', 'r')
for line in file.read().splitlines():
    print('/'.join(line.split('/',-1)[:-1]) + "<")
```